# .NET Core Catch Json Deserialization Error In Middleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm certain I'm missing something patently obvious.

Is it possible to handle JSON deserialization errors in .NET Core's default middleware/deserializer?  I need to be sure that a particular value is a JSON primitive and not an object/array.  If it's not a primitive, I'd like to terminate the request and return the appropriate status code before it gets to the controller.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] List<MyType> myTypes)
{
    // Logic ....

    return Created(new Uri("some-location/", UriKind.Relative), someValue);
}
```

Request body:

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "some value",
        "prop2": "some value",
        "prop3": null
    },
    {
        "prop1": "some value",
        "prop2": "some value",
        "prop3": {
            "prop3-1": "some value"
        }
    }
]
```

The `MyType` constructor inspects the arguments passed in and throws an exception if there's a problem.  `prop3` in `MyType` is a `dynamic` field.  I've verified that the exception is being thrown when the second item in the request body is deserialized.

This all feels pretty straightforward but I just can't find where to access the default deserializer.

I tried [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/) and it does catch errors but only after the request has made it into the controller.

Is there a way to handle this in JSON annotations?  I looked through the Newtonsoft docs but nothing jumped out.

Comment: If you don’t need this *generally* but just once or a very few times, you could accept the raw string body instead of your `List<MyType>` and deserialize it manually within your controller action. Otherwise, you will have to adjust the model binding mechanism and that is probably going to be a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1
I think what you are looking for is the AddJsonOptions()

in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
     options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Error;
});
```

This will not throw an exception, but it will fail to bind, so myTypes becomes null.

Then you can just add a null check

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] List<MyType> myTypes)
{
    if(myTypes == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // Logic ....

    return Created(new Uri("some-location/", UriKind.Relative), someValue);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the default behavior of the deserializer.  If I don't add any JsonOptions, my custom exception will be thrown and the list will be null when passed into the controller.  This remains true if the offending item is not the first item in the list.  The null check in the controller is definitely doable but I'd love to find a way for the deserializer exceptions to terminate the request.

Comment: @user2864874 It's not the default behavior. You said the list is null, but here the whole object is null. Are you using ASP.NET Core 2.1 by any chance? Then there's another way.

Comment: Using Core 2.0 but it's early enough in the project that I could upgrade.  Are you referring to the MyType object when you say the whole object is null?  If so, wouldn't the null list cause any successfully deserialized objects to be garbage collected?

Comment: @user2864874 myTypes will be null. Yes, if it's null it won't be saved anywhere